# Scale SVG Image mask on scroll and reveal the website content

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, gsap

I need to re-create this scrolling [animation](https://annajona.is/).

What I need is the following:

First when the user visit the website to see the animated logo (which I have).

Then when he start scrolling it will start revealing the website under the mask.

At the moment I'm playing with ScrollMagic and GSAP but I'm not sure that this is the right combination.